# How to decode HTML special character into their actual value?

Tags: c#, .net

How to encode HTML special character into their actual value?

**Data:**

```
Antique bronze of an archer by Franz Iffland Literature:&#8232;&ldquo;Bronzes, sculptors and founders&rdquo; by H. Berman, Abage. &#8232;&ldquo;Dictionnaire illustr&eacute; des sculpteurs animaliers &amp; fondeurs de l&rsquo;antiquit&eacute; &agrave; nos jours&nbsp;&ldquo; by Jean Charles Hachet. Argus Valentines. &#8232;&ldquo;The dictionary of sculptors in bronze&rdquo; by James Mackay. Antique collectors club. &#8232; Fedex shipping: $ 185
```

**Required output:**

```
Antique bronze of an archer by Franz Iffland Literature: “Bronzes, sculptors and founders” by H. Berman, Abage.  “Dictionnaire illustré des sculpteurs animaliers & fondeurs de l’antiquité à nos jours “ by Jean Charles Hachet. Argus Valentines.  “The dictionary of sculptors in bronze” by James Mackay. Antique collectors club.   Fedex shipping: $ 185
```

Comment: I think you can delete the question on your own nitin http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question

Comment: Rolled back the strange edit...

Comment: delete this question as it is duplicate

Comment: Flag it and leave it then. Don't do weird stuff. Stick to the rules of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) or [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode.aspx)

```
string s = "Antique bronze of an archer by Franz Iffland Literature:&#8232;&ldquo;Bronzes, sculptors and founders&rdquo; by H. Berman, Abage. &#8232;&ldquo;Dictionnaire illustr&eacute; des sculpteurs animaliers &amp; fondeurs de l&rsquo;antiquit&eacute; &agrave; nos jours&nbsp;&ldquo; by Jean Charles Hachet. Argus Valentines. &#8232;&ldquo;The dictionary of sculptors in bronze&rdquo; by James Mackay. Antique collectors club. &#8232; Fedex shipping: $ 185";
var s2 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
var s3 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `HtmlDecode`:

```
string source ="Antique bronze of an archer by Franz Iffland Literature:&#8232;&ldquo;Bronzes, sculptors and founders&rdquo; by H. Berman, Abage. &#8232;&ldquo;Dictionnaire illustr&eacute; des sculpteurs animaliers &amp; fondeurs de l&rsquo;antiquit&eacute; &agrave; nos jours&nbsp;&ldquo; by Jean Charles Hachet. Argus Valentines. &#8232;&ldquo;The dictionary of sculptors in bronze&rdquo; by James Mackay. Antique collectors club. &#8232; Fedex shipping: $ 185";

string decoded= WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 string output = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Data);
```

It comes under `System.Net` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
string res = Server.HtmlDecode("ntique bronze of an archer by Franz Iffland Literature:&#8232;&ldquo;Bronzes, sculptors and founders&rdquo; by H. Berman, Abage. &#8232;&ldquo;Dictionnaire illustr&eacute; des sculpteurs animaliers &amp; fondeurs de l&rsquo;antiquit&eacute; &agrave; nos jours&nbsp;&ldquo; by Jean Charles Hachet. Argus Valentines. &#8232;&ldquo;The dictionary of sculptors in bronze&rdquo; by James Mackay. Antique collectors club. &#8232; Fedex shipping: $ 185");
```